How can i read and write to cells in the same function?
I would like to read the spreadsheet cell H2 in the same function blackList
With this script, i am currently writing to cell H1. I would like to read cell H2 as well.
This is my updated script:
const { setTimeout } = require("timers/promises"); // cause a delay if needed

async function blackList() { 
    const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
    const spreadsheetId = "myidhere";
  
    const sheetName = "BOTDATA";
    const cells = ["H1"];
    const valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
    const userInput = interaction.options.get('steamid').value;
    await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId,
      range: `'${sheetName}'!${cells[0]}`,
      resource: { values: [[userInput]] },
      valueInputOption,
    });
     await setTimeout(1000); // set time on delay if needed

    const obj = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId, range: `'${sheetName}'!H2`});
    const value = obj.data.values[0][0];
   // console.log(value);
    return value;
  }

})()


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your question, it seems that there are several questions. Can I ask you about the details of your actual question? By the way, in your showing script, at (async () => { ,,, })(), this function is automatically run when the script is run. Is this your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

@Tanaike I only want the command to run when userInput is detected. That is my main question

My secondary question is to read the cell H2 after H1 has been written in.

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your 2 replies, I couldn't understand the answer to By the way, in your showing script, at (async () => { ,,, })(), this function is automatically run when the script is run. Is this your expected result?. And, how will you do My secondary question in this question?

@Tanaike so every time I use any of my commands on the bot, it will console log result.data, and write to the cell, I only want it to run when the check bl command is used. I try to remove console log and I get an error.

Sorry I am not the best at explaining, but after I write to cell H1 I want to read H2. I ONLY want to do that when I use blacklist function

Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

@Tanaike Sorry again, I have updated my question. I hope this helps you understand.

Thank you for replying and updating your question. I have a question for your updated question. About I would like to read cell H2 as well., how will you do the retrieved value from cell "H2"? Do you just want to retrieve a value from cell "H2?

Depending on the value of the cell 'H1' is when the userInput is updated, it will change cell "H2" Value. And i would like to display H2.
For example, in my interaction.commandname you see the  .setDescription(${userInput} is) it is displaying the userInput, but i would like it to be somthing like  .setDescription(${userInput} is ${blackList[H2]})`

I want to read cell H2 after H1 is updated.

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it.

Thank you for the help, it works but how do i use value outside of the function?

Thank you for replying. About your new question it works but how do i use value outside of the function?, before your new question, can I ask you whether my proposed script worked? My answer is for your question I want to read cell H2 after H1 is updated.

About your new question, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. But, if you call the function blackList at another function, for example, how about const value = await blackList()? And at that time, please add return value to just below the line of console.log(value); in the function blackList.

@Tanaike it works, but it gives me and error when i use it more than once, anything you can think of as to why? I will update my current script

Thank you for replying. About it works, I understood it. About but it gives me and error when i use it more than once, anything you can think of as to why?, unfortunately, I cannot know about it. So, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. By this, it will help a lot of users think of the reason and a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

@Tanaike I will do so, One last question, when i read value it comes up as [object Promise] any way i can change it to the actual value?

Thank you for replying. About I will do so, when I saw your new question, I would like to check it. About One last question, when i read value it comes up as [object Promise] any way i can change it to the actual value?, can you include your new questions into your new posted question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? By the way, please ask one question in one post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to put a value to a cell "H1" and want to retrieve a value from "H2". From Depending on the value of the cell 'H1' is when the userInput is updated, it will change cell "H2" Value. And i would like to display H2., it seems that the value "H2" is changed by the value of "H1".

In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
const { setTimeout } = require("timers/promises"); // added

async function blackList() {
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });
  const spreadsheetId = "myIdhere";

  const sheetName = "BOTDATA";
  const cells = ["H1"];
  const valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";
  const userInput = interaction.options.get("steamid").value;
  await sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId,
    range: `'${sheetName}'!${cells[0]}`,
    resource: { values: [[userInput]] },
    valueInputOption,
  });

  await setTimeout(2000); // Please adjust this value to your situation.

  const obj = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({spreadsheetId, range: `'${sheetName}'!H2`});
  const value = obj.data.values[0][0];
  console.log(value);
}


In this modification, after a value was put into the cell "H1", the cell value of "H2" is retrieved.
In this modification, the wait time is set for calculating the formula of "H2". But, I have no information about your actual situation. So, I'm not sure whether await setTimeout(2000); is required to be used. So, please test with and without it, and decide whether you use it.

Note:

setTimeout can be used after Node.js 16. Please be careful about this.

